# Background image disappearing

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image

I made a small (100x50) background image for my one page scroll website like this:

```
section:before
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    height: 105%;
    margin: -15px -15px 0 -15px;

    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
section.first-page:before
{
    background-image: url('/images/first-background.png');
}
```

And so I have four section with height set to 100%.

In chrome, this works perfectly, but in Firefox, the last two images are gone. I see a white background, and when I open the browser console, the images are loaded with 304. But what really sucks is that when opening the console sometimes or just reloading, the background reappears!!

[**Here is a demo**](https://opencubes.github.io)

Comment: The filter properties only work in specific browsers... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter Scrolling to the bottom will show you that the filter property does not work in Mozilla

Comment: @BuddhistBeast yes but I use url filter

Comment: Ahh, I see... Well I stand corrected.

Comment: have you tried `filter: url('blur.svg#blur');` ? Where the slash is removed?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast now yes, it didn't worked either